# Плагин начинает работать, но почему выполняется только одно действие?

Tags: java

Проблема в том, что когда плагин начинает работать, то выполняется только одно действие например если первым поставить проверку игрока, то проверка и будет, но на проверку аргументов будет выдавать ошибку, и наоборот, как сделать, чтобы было обе проверки? Вот код:

```
if (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0])==null) {
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"Игрок не в сети!");
    return true;
}

if (args.length==0||args.length>=2) { 
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"Ошибка, пишите /call [игрок]");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `return` завершает выполнение метода.

Comment: я же написал там return

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он порожден незнанием базовых конструкций языка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам **сначала нужно проверить корректность аргументов**, а потом проверить находится ли игрок в сети, т.е. просто поменять if-ы местами. Если не передать ни одного аргумента и сразу не проверить что передано необходимое их количество, а сначала пробовать читать первый аргумент - будет ошибка обращения к элементу за границами массива.

Технически - сначала нужно проверить что в массиве есть хотя бы один элемент (или ровно один), а потом уже обращаться к первому элементу массива.

```
// Если нужно чтобы был передан ровно один аргумент, достаточно такого условия:
if (args.length!=1) { 
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"Ошибка, пишите /call [игрок]");
    return true;
}

if (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0])==null) {
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"Игрок не в сети!");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь я всё понял